# How to query Azure Data Explorer from an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, azure-data-explorer

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/tds/tdskql) article one can create SSIS jobs to query Kusto with a KQL query.

How can this be done? How would one connect to and query ADX from an SSIS package?

Comment: What exactly is the question? The article shows examples of different ways to execute ADX queries. Do you have an issue with the connection? Do you get any errors?

Comment: The examples doesn't show the context as far as I can see. What is `csb` for example? What kind of connection would I use in my SSIS package? ADO.NET? Can I write C# in SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you'll have is that SSIS .NET Tasks don't really understand nuget. The design experience will allow you to build a script/component that uses a nuget package *but* the moment you close the designer, the packages folder is trashed/not serialized into the package. When the package Executes, the task/component will fail because the expected libraries are not there and the SSIS engine does not have the insight to call a package manager to fix it.

Blessedly, these DLLs ought to be strongly signed so making this work should be a matter of installing them into the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) on your development machine(s) and corresponding servers. Something like the following command, which might need to be run an admin context

```
gacutil -if \path\to\the\assembly\Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data.dll
```

You likely have a gacutil installed but not in your command path `dir /s /b gacutil.exe` will ferret out locations.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)>dir /s /b gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
```

From your comment, `what is csb for example` I presume based on [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-data) that it's a connection string builder object. Which makes sense, the code is requesting that it opens a SqlConnection object and the constructor needs to know where to go, what credentials to use, etc.